# Why can't one cast a ListPreference to a Preference? (android)

Tags: android, android-fragments

Given this inheritance tree

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.preference.Preference
       ↳    android.preference.DialogPreference
           ↳    android.preference.ListPreference
```

When I try to do

```
myListPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
```

I get this compile error:

> The method
>   setOnPreferenceClickListener(Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener) in
>   the type Preference is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   OnPreferenceClickListener(){})

Also when I try

```
myListPreference = getPreferenceManager().findPreference(DISPLAY_MESSAGE);
```

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Preference to ListPreference

Comment: aren't you trying to cast a Preference to a ListPreference? Inheritence only goes one way

Comment: @panini but if my runtime instance is a ListPreference, then I should be able to downcast

Comment: Yeah, but the compiler doesn't know that your runtime instance is a ListPreference, all it can see is that PreferenceManager##findPreference() returns a Preference. you could explicitly cast it if you wanted though.

Comment: @panini okay, but why cant I `setOnPreferenceClickListener()` on the ListPreference since it is a Preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two problems are *not* related.

Question 1:
You probably have an import statement missing. Try `new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener()` instead or add `import Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener`.

Question 2:
You can not implicitly upcast an object, you can only implicitly downcast.  You must do this `myListPreference = (ListPreference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference(DISPLAY_MESSAGE);`

For future reference:

```
SubClass obj = getSuperClass(); // Not Valid, must cast
SuperClass obj = getSubClass(); // Valid
```